# mysql_real_escape_string again if copying data?

Tags: php, mysql, database, escaping

Before I put data into my database I pass it through `mysql_real_escape_string`.

If I want to copy that same data into another table, do I need to pass it through `mysql_real_escape_string` again before I copy it?

I wrote a small script to test the issue and it looks like the answer is yes:

```
$db = new AQLDatabase();
$db->connect();

$title = "imran's color";
$title = mysql_real_escape_string($title);
$sql = "insert into tags (title, color) values  ('".$title."','@32324')";
$db->executeSQL($sql);

$sql = "select * from tags where color = '@32324' ";
$result = $db->executeSQL($sql);
while($row= mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $new_title =  $row['title'];
}

$new_title = mysql_real_escape_string($new_title);
$sql = "insert into tags (title, color) values  ('".$new_title."','DDDDD')";
$db->executeSQL($sql);
```

**NOTE: If I remove the second `mysql_real_escape_string` call, then the second insert won't take place**

Comment: What do you mean by copy? Extract it from one table and insert it into the other via SQL?

Comment: In that case, you'll need to apply `mysql_real_escape_string` again, since the data will not have the right escape sequences when it's retrieved from the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are doing something like this?

1. save mysql_real_escape_string($bla) to database
2. fetch $bla from database
3. save $bla again (in another table..)

Fetching $bla from the database will "unescape" it so it could be a harmful string again. Always escape it again when saving it.

Comment: ok your answer is completely different from the rest. Others are saying no need escape it again. Any source to back up your answer?

Comment: @Imran it is stated in your own question. Is your data going to database? What are you doing with data going to database?

Comment: i am just insert data into a table. Then using php to retrieve it and put it again into another table ( replication )

Comment: @Imran it doesn't matter where did you get it. You put it into query - so, you have to escape it, as you have said yourself. Origins of data doesn't matter. A database or a file or aliens space ship - it does not matter all. Sounds sensible?

Answer (score 1):

> Before I put data into my database I always make it go the Mysql_real_Escape_String thing.

You are doing right. Just keep it as is. Not database though but query it is.

The only note: only **strings** should be escaped using this function. It shouldn't be used with any other query parts.

> do I need to make it go through the Mysql_real_Escape_String again before I copy it?

Didn't you answer your question already? `Before I put [string-type] data into my [query] I always make it go the Mysql_real_Escape_String thing.` Is your data going to SQL query? So, here is an answer you have already.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are sure this data is already properly escaped, there is no need to.

mysql_real_escape_string is for 1) escaping 2) security purposes. Since it's your own data base and as long as you pass data to another database outside a potential hacker reach - you are already safe

Comment: 2) has nothing to do here. And you cannot be sure about data being "your own"

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel when you insert data into the table that was taken from user, you need to escape it. All of it. This is protecting you from SQL injection attacks and therefore is a security measure. If you work with the data of your own you can skip escaping unless you know that it is needed in this particular case. For example, always escape integers came from a client and never when they come from yourself.

Comment: Really? May be, you can explain, why?

Comment: Pedantic Note: Never escape integers.  Convert them to the proper type, and append them.  Escape Strings, Not Integers.  And best practice is to always escape or bind everything.  Then you can never get into a bad situation because something changed and what you could trust before you can't anymore.  Always treat any variable as if it contains bad data unless you specifically clean it right then...

Comment: @ircmaxell it is not "best practice" but rather explicit rule. It seems you do not understand it too. It's **data itself**, not it's source or origin being a reason for escaping/binding. `Strings should be escaped` is a syntax rule. No circumstance may cancel it.

Comment: @Col: It's not a rule since you can make it work without following it.  You can have an ENUM value which is known and be 100% safe without escaping it.  Best-Practice says that we should always escape everything, but that's not a hard rule (there are plenty of valid situations where escaping would be not necessary).  That's why I said best practice.

Comment: @ircmaxell although you're literally correct, these 2 upvotes on your comment means 2 another sql injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel it depends on situation. If enum value comes from user side - you are right. But having enum value in local variable and then escaping it when you insert it into a DB is excessive. Requiring database backend/class to escape all data it receives as an input is absolutely correct but is slightly outside the scope of the discussion.

Comment: yet it has nothing to do with security.

Comment: What exactly? Data escaping? Why not?

Comment: @FractalizeR: Escaping database input is a *correctness* issue, not just a security issue. Even perfectly legitimate data can (and will) cause problems if not escaped. In this case, re-escaping **is** necessary, because when the data are retrieved from the database, all those escape sequences that `mysql_real_escape_string` added the first time round won't be there any more. What happens when you try to insert it again now? Of course, the obvious solution is to use binding and forget about escaping, but your post is at best misleading and at worst incorrect.

Comment: @ Will Vousden I think this is just an argument over words. Correctness or not, if all database input was correctly escaped, it would certainly improve security of many projects a lot.

Comment: @FractalizeR : i have edited the question to include the solution

Answer (score -2):

Its already scaped, just copy it as is, if you want to undo the mysql_real_escape_string you can use `stripslashes($sting)` to remove it

PD: This is false and now i understand why.

Comment: That's the spirit, i usually don't answer questions and this is not going to help for me to keep trying.. i think it will be much more productive to tell us why is it lame that only to tag it as lame...

Comment: Data in the db is not escaped. you can't undo the mysql_real_escape_string() with stripslashes() - not all symbols will be converted properly, `\r\n` ones for example

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string` is used to escape data **for the query**. Once it's in the database, those escape sequences are gone, and need to be applied again if you use them in another query.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel. You see, your second comment help us all. First, nobody :) Thank you!